# Design pattern help for a controller and a wicket page

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I have a wicket page that will post a transaction. It takes in nett value and works out the commission and tax. A controller class is used to update the other values when one is changed. I've got it working but I feel the design isn't the best with regards to the controller as it has different update methods based on if its a gross or nett rated transaction.

My first thought was to have a nettController and a grossController, both inheriting from controller and using a factory to pick the correct one. I was having trouble getting this working with wicket due to it using @SpringBean.

```java
public class PostUnderwriterTransactionPanel extends AbstractPolicyCurrentAdhocTransactionPanel<PostUnderwriterTransactionContext>{

    @SpringBean
    public PostUnderwriterTransactionPanelController controller;

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();

        transactionDetails.add(grossAmountQuestion = createNettAmountTextField(GROSS_AMOUNT_ID, GROSS_AMOUNT_KEY));
        transactionDetails.add(nettAmountQuestion = createNettAmountTextField(NETT_AMOUNT_ID, NETT_AMOUNT_KEY));
        transactionDetails.add(nettAmountIncTax = createCurrencyTextField(NETT_INC_TAX_ID, NETT_INC_TAX_KEY));
        transactionDetails.add(commissionAmount = createCurrencyTextField(COMMISSION_AMOUNT_ID, COMMISSION_AMOUNT_KEY));
        transactionDetails.add(commissionRate = createPercentageTextField(COMMISSION_RATE_ID, COMMISSION_RATE_KEY));
        transactionDetails.add(taxAmount = createCurrencyTextField(TAX_AMOUNT_ID, TAX_AMOUNT_KEY));
        transactionDetails.add(taxRate = createPercentageTextField(TAX_RATE_ID, TAX_RATE_KEY));
        transactionDetails.add(totalAmount = createInfoPanel(TOTAL_AMOUNT_ID, TOTAL_AMOUNT_KEY));
        checkOverride(commissionAmount, commissionRate, OVERRIDE_INSURER_COMMISSION.getCode());
        checkOverride(taxAmount, taxRate, OVERRIDE_TAX.getCode());
        add(content);
        addEffectiveDateOnUpdate();
        getModelObject().getTransactionPosting().setAmount(0L);
        controller.setParameterValues(getModelObject());

        if(getModelObject().isNetRated()){
            grossAmountQuestion.setVisible(false);
        }else{
            nettAmountQuestion.setVisible(false);
            nettAmountIncTax.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public void checkOverride(TextField<Float> amount, TextField<Float> rate, String code){
        if(!controller.getOverrideAllowed(code, getPscm())){
            amount.setEnabled(false);
            rate.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private void redrawValues(AjaxRequestTarget target){
        if(getModelObject().isNetRated()) {
            target.add(nettAmountQuestion, nettAmountIncTax, commissionAmount, commissionRate, taxAmount, taxRate, totalAmount, newPolicyBalance);
        }
        else{
            target.add(grossAmountQuestion, commissionAmount, commissionRate, taxAmount, taxRate, totalAmount, newPolicyBalance);
        }
    }


    private void callControllerUpdate(String type){

        if(getModelObject().isNetRated()) {
            switch (type) {
                case NETT_AMOUNT_ID:
                    controller.updateNettAmount(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case NETT_INC_TAX_ID:
                    controller.updateNettIncTax(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case COMMISSION_AMOUNT_ID:
                    controller.updateCommissionAmount(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case COMMISSION_RATE_ID:
                    controller.updateCommissionRate(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case TAX_AMOUNT_ID:
                    controller.updateTaxAmount(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case TAX_RATE_ID:
                    controller.updateTaxRateFromTextBox(getModelObject());
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            switch (type) {
                case GROSS_AMOUNT_ID:
                    controller.updateGrossAmount(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case COMMISSION_AMOUNT_ID:
                    controller.updateGrossCommissionAmount(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case COMMISSION_RATE_ID:
                    controller.updateGrossCommissionRate(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case TAX_AMOUNT_ID:
                    controller.updateGrossTaxAmount(getModelObject());
                    break;
                case TAX_RATE_ID:
                    controller.updateGrossTaxRate(getModelObject());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}


@Component
public class PostUnderwriterTransactionPanelController extends AdhocTransactionViewControllerImpl {

    @Autowired
    private NettRatedCalculator nettRatedCalculator;

   public void updateNettAmount(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setNettAmountIncTax(nettRatedCalculator.calculateNettIncTax(context.getNettAmount(), context.getParameterTaxRate()));
        context.setCommissionAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionAmount(context.getCommissionFlatCharge(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getParameterCommissionRate()));
        context.setCommissionRate(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionRate(context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getNettAmount()));
        context.setTaxRate(context.getParameterTaxRate());
        context.setTaxAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxAmount(context.getParameterTaxRate(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateCommissionAmount(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setCommissionRate(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionRate(context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getNettAmount()));
        updateCommission(context);
    }

    public void updateCommissionRate(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        float equivalentCommission =  nettRatedCalculator.calculateEquivalentRate(context.getCommissionRate());
        context.setCommissionAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionAmount(0L, context.getNettAmount(), equivalentCommission));
        updateCommission(context);
    }

    private void updateCommission(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setNettAmountIncTax(nettRatedCalculator.calculateNettIncTax(context.getNettAmount(), context.getTaxRate()));
        context.setTaxAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxAmount(context.getTaxRate(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateTaxAmount(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setTaxRate(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxRate(context.getTaxAmount(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount()));
        context.setNettAmountIncTax(nettRatedCalculator.calculateNettIncTax(context.getNettAmount(), context.getTaxRate()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateTaxRateFromTextBox(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context) {
        context.setTaxAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxAmount(context.getTaxRate(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount()));
        context.setNettAmountIncTax(nettRatedCalculator.calculateNettIncTax(context.getNettAmount(), context.getTaxRate()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateTaxRateFromSystemParameter(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context) {
        context.setTaxRate(getTaxRateParameter(context.getPscm(), context));
        context.setTaxAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxAmount(context.getTaxRate(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount()));
        context.setNettAmountIncTax(nettRatedCalculator.calculateNettIncTax(context.getNettAmount(), context.getTaxRate()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateNettIncTax(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setNettAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateNettAmount(context.getNettAmountIncTax(), context.getParameterTaxRate()));
        context.setCommissionAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionAmount(context.getCommissionFlatCharge(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getParameterCommissionRate()));
        context.setCommissionRate(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionRate(context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getNettAmount()));
        context.setTaxAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxAmount(context.getParameterTaxRate(), context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount()));
        context.setTaxRate(context.getParameterTaxRate());
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getNettAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateGrossAmount(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context) {
        context.setTaxRate(context.getParameterTaxRate());
        context.setTaxAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxFromGross(context.getGrossAmount(), context.getTaxRate()));
        context.setCommissionRate(context.getParameterCommissionRate());
        context.setCommissionAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionGross(context.getCommissionRate(), context.getGrossAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getGrossAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateGrossCommissionAmount(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setCommissionRate(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionRateGross(context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getGrossAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getGrossAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateGrossCommissionRate(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setCommissionAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionAmountGross(context.getCommissionRate(), context.getGrossAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getGrossAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateGrossTaxAmount(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
       context.setTaxRate(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxRateGross(context.getTaxAmount(), context.getGrossAmount()));
       context.setCommissionAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionAmountGross(context.getCommissionRate(), context.getGrossAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
       context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getGrossAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }

    public void updateGrossTaxRate(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context){
        context.setTaxAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTaxAmountFromTaxRateGross(context.getGrossAmount(), context.getTaxRate()));
        context.setCommissionAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateCommissionAmountGross(context.getCommissionRate(), context.getGrossAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
        context.setTotalAmount(nettRatedCalculator.calculateTotalAmount(context.getGrossAmount(), context.getCommissionAmount(), context.getTaxAmount()));
    }
}
```

I’m pretty new to wicket but I’ve got it working. I think the code could be better. Any ideas one what I could do to improve the design?

Comment: Hi, what kind of problem are you having with @SpringBean?

Comment: Hello Andrea. What I want is to have two types of controller class, a gross  and net version bot subclasses of the controller. The panel would then assign the appropriate version of the controller to the controller reference. I couldn't get this work as the SpringBean would always just try and use the super class.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refactor your controller making two different components, it might help to do the same with your page. For example you could create two different page, one for net values and one for gross. You can even mount them with two different paths (es: /net and /gross). In this why you could inject the right controller into the corresponding page and avoid the

> if(getModelObject().isNetRated())

inside callControllerUpdate method.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: yeah, that had crossed my mind. I'll give it a try. Thanks Andrea. =)